# Obtener la URL actual del navegador Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Mi objetivo es conseguir descargar un PDF de forma automatizada con Selenium y Python. Para ello el navegador se ejecuta de forma automática --> Navega a través de un enlace al PDF --> Descargar PDF.

De este proceso los he conseguido por separado pero no todo seguido, me explico:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from time import sleep
import 

url = 'https://www.juntadeandalucia.es/eboja/2021/40/index.html'

driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedgedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

boja = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sumario boletín nº 40')
boja.click()
sleep(5)

import requests

url_pdf= driver.current_url
print(url_pdf)

r = requests.get(url_pdf, stream=True)

with open('.\\boja_descargados\\boja1.pdf', 'a') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Descargar el pdf me funciona pero no consigo que me coja la URL después del cambio de pestaña al abrir el enlace al PDF.
He intentado

```
driver.current_url
```

pero me devuelve la primera URL:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y no la nueva que sería:
**https://www.juntadeandalucia.es/eboja/2021/40/BOJA21-040-00012_00003686.pdf**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de ejecutar `boja.click()` puedes obtener su atributo *href* mediante `boja.get_attribute('href')` y asignarlo a `url_pdf` para descargarlo con `requests.get`.

Puedes cambiar la *url actual* sin abrir una pestaña nueva mediante `driver.get(url_pdf)`, pero **para descargar el *PDF* no es necesario abrirlo en el navegador**.

Por ejemplo:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

url = 'https://www.juntadeandalucia.es/eboja/2021/40/index.html'

driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path='msedgedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

boja = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sumario boletín nº 40')
url_pdf = boja.get_attribute('href')

print(url_pdf) # https://www.juntadeandalucia.es/eboja/2021/40/BOJA21-040-00012_00003686.pdf

driver.get(url_pdf) # Si quieres navegar a la url del pdf en la misma pestaña (no es necesario para descargar el pdf)

r = requests.get(url_pdf, stream=True)

with open('boja1.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

`r.content` es un objeto de la clase `bytes`, así que para escribirlo en un archivo debes utilizar `open` en *modo "wb"*.

Un saludo!

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Exactamente eso era lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Genial! Me alegro amigo. Un saludo! ^^